# How to make Stockfish always give the score from white's perspective in Winboard?

Tags: stockfish, babaschess, winboard

I use Stockfish 4 to analyze chess games in both Babaschess and Winboard.  From time to time, Stockfish outputs a line with info like time, score, principal variation, etc.  In Babaschess, the 'score' behaves as I would expect; it is always from white's perspective.  If white is doing well, the score is always positive; if black is doing well, the score is always negative.  However, in Winboard, the score is always from the perspective of the current player, meaning that it tends to veer from positive-negative-positive-negative, if one player stays in the lead.

How can I get the score to behave in Winboard as it does in Babaschess, and always be from white's perspective; always negative if black is doing well?  Here's the line in my Winboard 'tags' that I use to load the Stockfish engine:

```
"Stockfish" -fcp "stockfish_4_32bit.exe" -fd "C:\Program Files\BabasChess\Engines\stockfish-4-win\Windows" -fUCI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/firstScoreAbs true` command option (*Tested in version 4.7.2*):

> If this option is set, the score reported by the engine is taken to be
>   that in favor of white, even when the engine plays black.

```
"stockfish_4_32bit.exe" -fd "path\Stockfish" -fUCI  /firstScoreAbs true
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I should add that this appears to be an XBoard/WinBoard specific argument, not a Stockfish specific argument.  I guess it can be specified for any chess engine.